# ASP.NET MVC compile fail when unchecked precompiled site updatable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, precompile

When I publish my website, if I uncheck the "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" I get bunch compile errors.

All the pages where I have `@using myNameSpace` referenced complain about "can't find reference". I am pretty sure all the pages work since I just tested it. If I leave the allow "updatable" checked then everything works fine - no error and the site runs perfectly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what are the compile errors?

Comment: @CodeNotFound can't find reference